# Epiphany crashes

Tags: web-browsers, crash

I have the Epiphany web browser running 24/7 to display up-to-date weather on a monitor from WeatherUnderground but it keeps on crashing by next morning.

I am not sure how to figure out what is causing this. Sometimes you have to also reboot the device in order to relaunch the browser. Could this be a memory issue?

EDIT:

```
grep "oom-killer" /var/log/syslog*
```

returned no results.

EDIT 2:

Tried this as well:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=118118

What I noticed was the browser did not crash after using EDIT 2 but now it just hangs and does use up most if not all the system memory.

GPU Memory has also been set at 256MB of Ram

EDIT 3:
Edit2 did not work. Edit1 seems to have caused the crashes to happen more often.

Comment: It's not impossible for it to be a memory issue.  Try `grep "oom-killer" /var/log/syslog*`.  That applies to stock Raspbian and probably most but not all other distros.

Comment: No luck with that. I just see default cron jobs running.

Answer (score 3):

You could try an hourly run of the command
free -mht.

Something like the below example and placing this executable under
/etc/cron.hourly. Files must not have .extensions.

#!/bin/bash

free -mht >> /tmp/memoryuse >/dev/null 2>&1

You could also try increasing gpu_mem allocation in the /boot/config.txt